# With the help of multiple excel files, create a Master Dataframe by choosing or extarcting specific columns from those files using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

1. On a daily basis, I am combining many excel (37+) files by selecting specific columns from them to create a master data set.
2. write Now I am doing this manually, which I want to automate by using Python.
3. I also wrote a small python script for the same, but it also updated manually 2 or 3 times within a week due to the lack of a standard format for columns across all excel workbooks, which I am getting from the client, and it will take more than 3 or 4 months to stabilise the format. Up till now, they are not going to provide me with an excel file with constant column headers.
4. So I just came across an idea, which I am not sure whether it is going to work or not
5. I will try my best to explain it in the proper way. I hope it will help you to understand the problem and simultaneously help me to get a solution to my problem.

**I have received 2 excel files from a client with the names Tata and BMW, respectively. PFB data within that file.**

Tata.xlsx

| Reg number | Chasis |
| --- | --- |
| abc@34 | 123-09 |
| 1234 | 34/lk |
| up-mh | mol\12 |

BMW.xlsx

| Car_Engine Number | Car_Reg# |
| --- | --- |
| dsdf | 12312 |
| - | xcas |
| poloq | mh12 |

***DataFrame*** after combining Tata and BMW ***xlsx*** files.

| Company | Car_Reg_No# | Car_Engine No# | Car_ChasisNo# |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tata | abc@34 | - | 123-09 |
| Tata | 1234 | - | 34/lk |
| Tata | up-mh | - | mol\12 |
| BMW | 12312 | dsdf | - |
| BMW | xcas | - | - |
| BMW | mh12 | poloq | - |

***One twist is here.***

As I mentioned, files come with no stable format of header, so I created 1 excel file template with a standard header which I feel matches with those excel file headers.

PFB table of template.xlsx

| Company | Car_Reg_No# | Car_Engine No# | Car_ChasisNo# |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tata | Reg number | - | Chasis |
| BMW | Car_Reg# | Car_Engine Number | - |

Now I am just explaining my idea.

I will load all files coming from clients, including manually created template files as well, and then we will run for a loop by considering template.xlsx data.

I will go to company columns and will do row Iterations like if its find Tata company name then it will go within folder find out tata file and then checking for columns is available within it or not if yes then it will append within dataframe like within Tata.xlsx **Vehicle registration number** comes with name **Reg number** so we will update this under the **Car_Reg_No#** header tag as we created by *condaring its standard name for our process*.

and same process will apply for the rest of columns.

***And it will create a column in the data frame with the company name, which will help us to understand which company they have added to it.***

We created Temlate.xlsx because if in the future, someone asks us to add some more columns to the dataframe, we will only add those names in the template columns, and then it will pick the columns by matching them with company column names. Due to this process, we will have to just keep focusing on the template file.

PFA scrren shot explaining Overall synopsis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/797gx.png)

Thank you ....|

Comment: Is the order of columns (of the two files) not stable as well or just the headers ? Does the changing headers have a pattern ? Also, can you share the script you wrote ?

Comment: Yes columns as well not stable but I think its not going to affect the process.

Comment: @abokey I'm new to Stack Overflow and have no idea how to share a script with someone; could you please guide me through the process?

Comment: Hi, you can just copy paste it in your post. Read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: pfa link : https://notebooksharing.space/view/958ebc9f5111f7b05ac3ed1a7ad486f3cc8f78c565ba4e3f081333d424ab8efd#displayOptions=

Comment: @abokey I shared my code link. Kindly now help me with the same.

Comment: @abokey What's happening I provided the code as you requested. I am kindly requesting you to help me with the same.

Comment: Does the changing headers have a pattern ? Can you give 2-3 examples of the headers the client gives you ?

Comment: @abokey Yes sure.Kindlly see above at Tata.xlsx table there Registration no. header is come with Reg number but in some files it comes like "REG#" in another file like "reg no#" same things happed with rest of the columns.